# Convert ANY number to Uint64 and back

Tags: c#, vb.net, types

I would like to convert ANY number to ULong and back. For example:

> Byte: 255, Short: -12, (U)Integer: 4,294,967,290, Float: -444

To convert a negative number to ulong AND back I thought of Bitconverter.
The problem is that if I call "BitConverter.GetBytes(Byte)" for example I get a byte array with a length of 1. But calling Bitconverter.ToUint64 requires a byte array of length 8 etc.

The purpose is that I'm using https://github.com/discretelogics/TeaFiles.Net to store a large amount of .NET structures with different values in it. But declaring a structure requires a specific type of properties. I cannot use the property "Object" for a value else it would be easy. And I cannot use a class as property but I can use ULong. This is just for people who starts asking why.

Comment: While you can convert a `float` to and from a `uint`, you're going to lose *something*, most likely everything to the right of the decimal point.

Comment: You need to sort out the difference between type conversion and reinterpret casting. The first changes a value from one type to another with a possible change in range and precision, e.g. `smallint` to `long`. The second simply changes the _interpretation_ of a set of bits from one type to another, e.g. `ulong` to `double` since they are both 64-bit values. Note that round trip reinterpret casts, e.g. `double` to `ulong` to `double`, should result in no loss of precision. A 128-bit type like `decimal` will present a challenge.

Comment: Not real clear on what you're trying to achieve, but can you use `ValueType` wherever you wanted to use `Object`?